# Como fazer a inversão do que é recebido com acréscimo de vírgula?

Tags: python

Programa que recebe um nome via teclado e deve imprimir o sobrenome, primeiro nome e demais nomes abreviados
ex.: recebe "Luis Costa Santos" e retorna "Santos, Luis C."

```
lista = []
nome = ''
answer = ''
i = 0

while answer != 'n':
    nome = str(input('ponha o seu nome: '))
    lista.append(nome)
    answer = str(input('deseja continuar? s ou n: '))
    if answer == 's':
        i += 1
    else:
        break

print(lista)
```

Comment: Dúvida: por que está lendo vários nomes? O enunciado pede que seja lido apenas um, então esse laço de repetição não fez sentido.

Comment: Homero, como ficaria o nome "Fulano da Silva"?? Ficaria `Silva, Fulano d.` ou `Silva, Fulano D.` ou `Silva, Fulano` ??

Comment: A primeira opção Silva, Fulano D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você vai precisar seguir os seguinte passos:

1. quebrar o nome completo por espaços (usando [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) por exemplo)
2. separar o último sobrenome ([`list.pop()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)) e manter inalterado
3. separar o primeiro nome ([`list.pop(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)) e manter inalterado
4. pegar apenas a primeira letra do restante do nome
5. concatenar a resposta

Exemplo:

```
def converte_nome(nome):
    nome = nome.split()

    primeiro_nome = nome.pop(0)
    sobrenome = nome.pop()

    restante = [primeiro_nome] + [n[0] + "." for n in nome]
    restante = " ".join(restante)

    return f"{sobrenome}, {restante}"

print(converte_nome('Luis Carlos Costa'))
# Costa, Luis C.
print(converte_nome('Fernando Sávio Rosback Dominguez'))
# Dominguez, Fernando S. R.
print(converte_nome('João Silva'))
# Silva, João
```

[Código funcionando](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/IrritatingCanineTrialsoftware).

Comment: é que a função "def" não foi passada em aula ainda, por isso eu fico em dúvida se haveria como resolver a questão sem ela.
muito obrigado!

Comment: os nomes têm que ser digitados, não estando pré-selecionados.

Comment: É só um exemplo. Você poderia usar a função `input` ao invés de usar uma string pronta

Comment: colocando "nome = str(input('digite o nome: '))" antes da função "def", o que devo alterar no programa que tu fez?
desculpe a pergunta, é que ainda não trabalhei com o "def".

Comment: Estou no celular agora mas você pode colocar seu código antes do `def`, apagar a linha do `def`, retirar os espaços antes do corpo da função e substituir o `return` por um `print`

Comment: VALEU FERNANDO!!!

Comment: consegui montar o código melhorado

Comment: lista = []
nome = ''
answer = ''
i = 0
while answer != 'n':
    nome = str(input('ponha o seu nome: '))
    lista.append(nome)
    answer = str(input('deseja continuar? s ou n: '))
    if answer == 's':
        i += 1
    else:
        break
print(lista)
nome = nome.split()

primeiro_nome = nome.pop(0)
sobrenome = nome.pop()

restante = [primeiro_nome] + [n[0] + "." for n in nome]
restante = " ".join(restante)

print(sobrenome,',', restante)

Comment: tirei o laço de repetição porque quando havia mais de um nome digitado não ocorria o que devia

lista = []
nome = ''
answer = ''
i = 0
nome = str(input('ponha o seu nome: '))
lista.append(nome)
print(lista)
nome = nome.split()
primeiro_nome = nome.pop(0)
sobrenome = nome.pop()
restante = [primeiro_nome] + [n[0] + "." for n in nome]
restante = " ".join(restante)
print(sobrenome,',', restante)

Comment: Que bom que deu certo Homero. Mas o mais importante, você conseguiu entender o código? Se não conseguiu eu te explico melhor

Comment: esta parte do código ficou um pouco confusa para mim, pois são funções que não conhecia: nome = nome.split() primeiro_nome = nome.pop(0) sobrenome = nome.pop() restante = [primeiro_nome] + [n[0] + "." for n in nome] restante = " ".join(restante) –

Comment: O método `str.split` quebra uma string em uma lista de acordo com o separador passado como parâmetro. Se nenhum parâmetro for passado, o método usa whitespaces como separador (quebra de linha, tabulação, espaços, etc...). O método `list.pop` remove um elemento da lista e retorna ele para você usar. Este método recebe como parâmetro o índice da lista o qual você quer remover, se nenhum parâmetro for passado ele retira o último elemento da lista. Por isso meu código usa `nome.pop(0)` para pegar o primeiro nome e `nome.pop()` para pegar o último

Comment: O método `str.join()` faz o reverso do split. Ele une uma lista usando um separador que você escolher. Você pode pesquisar por *list comprehension* para entender melhor o que faço ou perguntar aqui no site. Tem muita gente entendida de python aqui. :D

Comment: Você poderia usar *slices* como o @nosklo usou para pegar partes da lista

Comment: tentei utilizar o dele e não consegui

Comment: valeu fernando!!!

Answer (score 2):

O código que você passou não tem quase nada a ver com a pergunta - ele somente lê os nomes e adiciona em uma lista!

Esse exemplo pega um nome que esteja na variável `nome` e aplica o que você fez. Inicialmente ele divide o nome todo em palavras separadas, e então trata cada palavra separadamente:

```
palavras = nome.split()
novo_nome = ' '.join([  #monta o novo nome, composto de:
    palavras[-1] + ',', # ultimo nome seguido de virgula
    palavras[0],        # primeiro nome
] + [palavra[0] + '.'   # primeira letra seguida de ponto
    for palavra in palavras[1:-1]]) # dos demais nomes do meio
```

Testando, com `nome = "Luis Costa Santos"` o resultado é o esperado:

```
Santos, Luis C.
```